# Linking Contacts using Exchange Web Services

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, mapi, ewsjavaapi

I am trying to link contacts (and also to look up what the linked contacts are) via Exchange Web Services. So far, I have been able to retrieve this information using extended properties. Specifically, I am looking up the property `PidLidContactLinkEntry`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee158201%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

According to the documentation there, the links reference Address book `EntryID`s. As far as I can tell, these are different than the given contact's Entry ID but seem to contain the contact's entry ID.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee160588%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Does anyone know how to handle this via EWS?

For the record, I am using the EWS Java API.

Comment: Linking contacts - to or with what?

Comment: Links in contacts or tasks, i.e. a given contact or task will have a link or a series of links to another contact.